# FXML LoadException

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with making scene appear in my program.I have not finished the controller class yet, i just wanted to fix the main problem of it not being able to run in the first place. NB. this addpressed method is what is going to open open this createvideo fxml file.This is a method from another class which is working completely fine.

```
@FXML
public void addPressed() {
    final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("CreateVideo.fxml"));
    final CreateVideo controller = new CreateVideo();
    loader.setController(controller);
    try {
        final Parent parent = (Parent) loader.load();

        final Stage removeStage = new Stage();
        removeStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        removeStage.setScene(new Scene(parent, 250, 200));
        removeStage.showAndWait();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Createvideo.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class CreateVideo {

    @FXML
    private boolean Owned;
    private String titleText;
    private String directorText;
    private String Comment;
    private int playingTime;

    public CreateVideo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @FXML
    public void create() {
    
    }

    @FXML
    public void cancel() {
        
    }

}
```

this is the code for the fxml file i made

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="575.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="295.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="106.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="506.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="494.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Title:" />
      <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="35.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Director:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="102.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Playing Time:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="169.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Comment" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Own" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
      <CheckBox fx:id="Owned" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="60.0" top="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </CheckBox>
      <TextField fx:id="titleText" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="directorText" layoutX="116.0" layoutY="25.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="Comment" alignment="TOP_LEFT" layoutX="116.0" layoutY="69.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="367.0" prefWidth="600.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.rowSpan="2" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#create" text="Create" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="60.0" top="5.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <Button alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancel" text="Cancel" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Button>
      <Slider fx:id="playingTime" blockIncrement="30.0" majorTickUnit="30.0" max="360.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" value="120.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </Slider>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</GridPane>
```

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Eclipse%20workspace/uk.ac.aston.oop.javafx.assessed.video/target/classes/uk/ac/aston/oop/javafx/assessed/CreateVideo.fxml:29

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at src/uk.ac.aston.oop.javafx.assessed.ListController.addPressed(ListController.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set boolean field uk.ac.aston.oop.javafx.assessed.CreateVideo.Owned to javafx.scene.control.CheckBox
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeBooleanFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeBooleanFieldAccessorImpl.java:86)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1173)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:868)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:762)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    ... 60 more
```

Comment: If you have an exception, put the *complete* stack trace as text in the question, formatted as code.

Comment: Follow [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) consistently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your controller. In your fxml- Code you have some fx:ids set. These are used to refer to a object in the controller.

In your case the CheckBox with fx:id="Owned" tries to refere to an attribute of type **CheckBox** called "owned". But in the controller its a boolean.

In the controller you need to write: `@FXML private CheckBox owned;`
(Java naming conventions say that attributes should start lower case)

If you want to access the boolean value whether the checkbox is checked you need to access an attribute of the *owned* checkbox. You can do this by `owned.isSelected()`.

Hope i could help you?

PS: *@FXML* Annotation only applies for one attribute (the one after it); might be a bug you face soon

Comment: Thank you so much, that did indeed help

Comment: Note that the message in the stack trace tells you what is wrong: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set boolean field uk.ac.aston.oop.javafx.assessed.CreateVideo.Owned to javafx.scene.control.CheckBox`